# Estimating NE for continuous, zero-sum games.

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I am interested in estimating Nash Equilibria to symmetric, continuous two-player games of the following form.
Let :

$x_1$ - Player A's action

$x_2$ - Player B's action

where $x_1$, $x_2$ $\in [0,1]$ (the unit interval)

We denote the payoffs of the 2 players to be $f(x_1,x_2)$ and $-f(x_1,x_2)$ respectively.

where:

f is a known symmetric, non-convex function, ie. $f(x_1,x_2)$ = $-f(x_2,x_1)$
and is continuous almost everywhere.

Thus, the NE for both players is an unknown probability distribution over the interval, which is a 'function' of $f$.

No-regret algorithms should converge to the NE if the action space is finite, but in the above case it is continuous.  Are there any general algorithms which 'converge' to the NE for games with continuous action spaces?

Comment: Sidenote:  This relates to attempting to find the Nash Equilibria for the 3-battlefield, sequential, symmetric, continuous Blotto game, where each player places troop allocations one battlefield at a time.  Since the game is solved for the 2-battlefield case, this  is a 'first-step' problem on the first field.

The 'first-step' problem can rewritten as the estimating the NE for the above problem and I have a semi-decent estimate, which relied on finding regions of positive probability of play via sample play and optimising it with a Fourier basis, but 'convergence' is slow.